# mysql query two database tables, users and usermeta and sort by custom meta int value

Tags: users, query, wpdb, user-meta, php

I am trying to get an array of site users sorted by a custom meta value (an int).

I can query the users just fine and get them back to use in a foreach. I currently have the query results come back sorted already by display_name from the users table. I want it to sort by the custom usermeta value.

Any ideas on how to modify this query to get this done?

```
function get_all_top_members() {
    global $wpdb;
   $gather_users = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."users ORDER BY display_name ASC";
$all_users = $wpdb->get_results($gather_users);
return $all_users;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get a proper sort on the `meta_value` column because the values stored there aren't treated as integer values, but you can use a method similar to how it was done it WordPress back when we were using `meta_value_num` to do sorting, which basically involved adding a number onto the front of the data.

```
function get_users_ordered_by_meta( $key = '', $d = 'ASC' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $d = ( strtoupper( $d ) == 'DESC' ) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
    if( '' == $key )
        return;
    $r = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT u.ID, u.display_name, u.user_nicename, um.meta_value 
        FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} um, {$wpdb->users} u
        WHERE um.user_id = u.ID
        AND um.meta_key = %s
        ORDER by (0 + um.meta_value) $d
    ", $key ) );
    return $r;
}
```

This then gives you a proper sort on the meta value column.

Figured you might like a function so you can call it wherever you need it, just pass it the meta key you have setup for users, and optionally change the sort order.

```
$yourvar = get_users_ordered_by_meta('your-key');
```

Sort descending.

```
$yourvar = get_users_ordered_by_meta('your-key', 'desc');
```

You'll get an array of objects returned just like before, so i'll assume you know how to loop over that data and appropriate it for display, etc...(if not, post a comment).

Comment: Pure genius, you my man are amazing. Worked perfectly and can now be reused for a couple other things that i need to access and sort.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
global $wpdb;
$gather_users = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'META_KEY_HERE' ORDER BY $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value ASC");
$all_users = $wpdb->get_results($gather_users);
return $all_users;
```

and change META_KEY_HERE to your meta key

Comment: Didnt work for me, thanks for the effort though!

Comment: what didn't work? it returns an array list of ids in a sorted manner

Comment: The sort won't come out correctly like that, try it with a custom field holding a numeric sort value and watch what happens to the results.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are doing too much work : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'YOUR_KEY',
                'value'   => 'whatever_value_you\'re_looking_for',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    )
 );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Like other WP{{Query}} type conventions, you can orderby, limit result count, etc ...

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

edit - Caveat: this assumes you are assigning custom user data to the wp_core anticipated user table(s) - which in the OP it looks like you are. For custom tables, you'll want to go the $wpdb approach described by another user